# Load plugin class in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using `wordpress 4.9.8` and `PHP 7.1.8` I want to load a function from my class.

The plugin class is located under:

> C:\Users\admin\Desktop\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\content-creator\includes\SinglePostContent.php

My `function.php` file is with the following folder:

> C:\Users\admin\Desktop\wordpress\wp-content\themes\rehub-blankchild\functions.php

The function I would like to load looks like the following:

```
class SinglePostContent
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        //...
    }

    public function main($postID)
    {
      //...
    }
```

I tried to use the

```
add_action('wp_ajax_updateContent', 'updateContent');
function updateContent()
{

    $post_id = intval($_POST['post_id']);

    try {
        SinglePostContent::main($post_id); // HERE I get the error!
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
    wp_die();

}
```

Any suggestion how to load the class `SinglePostContent` within my `function.php`

Comment: Does the `SinglePostContent` exist in a specific namespace that you are not referencing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the method as static which is not. You need to instantiate the class and then call the method like this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_updateContent', 'updateContent');

function updateContent(){

    $post_id = 1;
    $single_post_content = new SinglePostContent;
    try {

        $single_post_content->main( $post_id );  
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        echo $e;
    }
    wp_die();
}
```